# Clear Android Market Search History?

Tags: 2.1-eclair, samsung-galaxy-s, google-play-store

Any thoughts on how one might clear the Android Marketplace search history?
For instance, if I recently searched for an android app in the marketplace, the marketplace search maintains a history list of which apps/keywords that I have recently looked for.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the **home screen** go to **Settings > Applications > Manage applications > All > Market** then choose  **"Clear data."**

This will erase your market search history.  When you go back into the market it'll be like your first time.  They will ask you to agree to the terms and condition again and then it'll be just like it was before without your search history.  Your app Downloads and Purchases list will still be there because that list is stored online in your Google account.

Comment: note that clearing market search history has been added to Market 3.1

Answer (score 3):

[HistoryEraser](http://www.appbrain.com/app/historyeraser/jp.androdev.historyeraser) claims to be able to clear this for you.  It can also clear YouTube, Maps, and Earth dearch histories as well.  I haven't used it in a while, though.  (Ever since I upgraded from 1.6 to CyanogenMod 6).

Answer (score 2):

According to a Google Support forum post, [clearing search history feature is added on Market 3.1](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Android+Market/thread?tid=2f51dab124381377&hl=en): open the Market app, press Menu > Settings, and then touch "Clear search history."